# How do you get the default IIS Directory in a Wix install package?

Tags: iis, wix, wix3

I Would like to set my default install location in Wix to go the default IIS directory

usually C:\inetpub\wwwroot\

in the XML i have

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="myProduct">
```

I Assume i can change either the ProgramFilesFolder directory the the TARGETDIR to one that matches with an IIS property. (in case the default location is moved on a machine)

What would that be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a registry search to find the location:

```
<Property Id="INSTALLLOCATION"> 
    <RegistrySearch Id="FindInetPubFolder" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp" Name="PathWWWRoot" Type="directory" /> 
</Property>
```

But I would caution you that I don't typically do this.  I tend to either create new websites or new virtual directories and use use ProgramFiles\Company\Product\WebSites\WebSite as where I put my files.  This allows safer integration with whatever other web sites that might also exist on the box.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not 100% happy with my own answer.  INSTALLLOCATION is immutable once a product is installed and should never be changed during a repair or other reinstall.  A better technique is to assign the registry search to another property and then assign this property to INSTALLLOCATION only if Not Installed.